# Import angularjs minified version

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, exports-loader

I'm using webpack, angular 1.x and have the following code

```
import angular from 'angular';
```

which works good, but the problem is that included file is too big (angularjs - 1.15mb). It will be better of course to use minified version of angularjs, but when I change code to

```
import angular from 'angular/angular.min.js';
```

it doesn't work properly, I mean it seems like `angular.min.js` doesn't export appropriate `angular` object.

What's the right way to use minified version of library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found [github issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1921) regarding the problem, it's good idea to use [exports-loader](https://github.com/webpack/exports-loader). My solution is:

*webpack.config.js*

```
...
// Add alias, so webpack looks for minified version of angular
resolve: {
    alias: {
        angular: "angular/angular.min.js"
    }
}

...
// Add exports loader for angular
modules: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /angular\.min\.js$/,
            loader: 'exports?angular'
        }
    ]
}
```

After this configuration we can easily import minified version of angular using the following command

```
let angular = require('angular');

// or es6 version

import angular from 'angular';
```

Comment: As of Webpack 2 you need a '-loader' prefix when specifying the loader, so it's: `loader: 'exports-loader?angular'`. You also need to `npm install --save-dev exports-loader`

Comment: is there any successful example of using exports-loaders without webpack? I am having trouble translating the webpack config into require()

Answer (score -3):

U can use angular cli and just type

ng build -prod

Then your  minified file are in dist foldeer. It must be smaller, and u can upload that ini your public_html

Comment: Thanks, I use angular 1.x

Comment: Downvote for failing to recognise he's asking about AngularJS, not Angular.